# JPA Annotation @OneToMany relation distinct records

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, one-to-many

I have two entities - software and employee - with an oneToMany relationship and they are on the same level.

```
@Entity(name = "EMPLOYEE") 
public class Employee {

        private long employeeId;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private List<Software> software;


        @Id //signifies the primary key
        @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID", nullable = false)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        public long getEmployeeId() {
            return employeeId;
        }

        public void setEmployeeId(long employeeId) {
            this.employeeId = employeeId;
        }

        @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", length = 50)
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false,length = 50)
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        @OneToMany(
              fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              orphanRemoval = true,
              targetEntity = Software.class)
        @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        public List<Software> getSoftware() {
            return software;
        }

        public void setSoftware(Software software) {
            this.software = software;
        }
}
```

Software.class

```
@Entity(name = "SOFTWARE") 
public class SOFTWARE {

    private long softwareId;
    private String softwareName;
    private String version; 
    private Employee emp;

    @Id 
    @Column(name = "SOFTWARE_ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getSoftwareId() {
        return softwareId;
    }

    public void setSoftwareId(long softwareId) {
        this.softwareId = softwareId;
    }

    @Column(name = "SOFTWARE_NAME")  
    public String getSoftwareName() {
        return softwareName;
    }

    public void setSoftwareName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "SOFTWARE_VERSION")  
    public String getSoftwareVersion() {
        return softwareDesc;
    }

    public void setSoftwareVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID", nullable = true)
    public String getEmployee() {
        return emp;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee emp) {
        this.emp = emp;
    }
}
```

The idea is to have a gui with a list of software where records could be deleted, added and assigned to each employee.

[image]

In my case i will have duplicate software records which differ only in the employee_id. The problem is if i edit a record it will not affect all records and if i delete the relationship i don't want to delete the record as itself because if it is deleted i could not assign this software to another employee.

Is this the right way or could the problem solved with @JoinTable by creating an third table? 
Does somebody has an idea?

Comment: Don't use CascadeType.ALL

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `CascadeType.ALL`. This will include cascading the remove operation with the effect, that if you delete an employee, the related software records will be deleted too. I'd start with no cascade at all.